# Running Django with Run can not find LESS CSS

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I have a Django project that uses buildout. When running or debugging the application it runs fine by using my buildout script. I also use django-compressor to compress and compile my LESS files. I installed LESS server side with node and you can access the lessc binary from the shell as normal. django-compressor runs Popen to run the lessc command. When it does this and exception gets thrown: `/bin/sh: lessc: command not found`.

If I run /bin/sh lessc it finds it. If I drop into the interactive python and run P`open(['/bin/sh', '-c', 'lessc'])` it finds it. What shell or environment does the running of Django in PyCharm use and how can I set it up to read either /etc/paths or $HOME/.bashrc, etc. lessc is located at /usr/local/bin which is in /etc/paths.

I am on Mac OSX 10.7, btw

Thanks for any support,
Travis

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue. To fix this I opened terminal and

```
$ which lessc
```

which gave me /usr/local/bin/lessc

next, in Pycharm i opened the Run/Debug configurations for my project.

Under the Django server drop down I selected my project.

In the configuration view to the right click the '...' after the 'Environment variables:' field.

In this Environment Variables window I added a new line with the following data:
PATH (the name)
/usr/local/bin (the value)

Ensure "Include parent environment variables" is checked.

Click OK
Click Apply/OK

Done

Best of luck!

Comment: It works! My parent environment has already contained the `PATH` and the `PATH` contained the `/usr/local/bin`, why not works?

Comment: For me it was nvm installation path. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5):

As pointed in Django compressor docs, you can use:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/less', 'lessc {infile} {outfile}'),
)
```

But probably for some reason Django could not find the lessc binary. So then just enter it with its full name:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/less', '/usr/local/bin/lessc {infile} {outfile}'),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the `lessc` binary.  There's a few different ways to get it.  Personally, I prefer to use the non-NodeJS method to install it (on Debian-based distros, like Ubuntu):

`sudo apt-get install node-less yui-compressor`

It will install it into one of the following locations:

```
/usr/local/bin/lessc
/usr/bin/lessc
```

Which, should be in your PATH already.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was solved by adding this to `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'static_precompiler.finders.StaticPrecompilerFinder',
]
```

Also make sure `lessc` is installed

```
which lessc
```